# MySQL Select Distinct Records from more than one column of table

Tags: mysql

Hi i am not sure if this is possible:-
I have a table named delivery with many columns and it is very huge table, and this is a source table from my adserver.

Out of many columns i want to fetch `DISTINCT` of 3 columns ( campaign, placement, site ) i.e Distinct campaigns from delivery and distinct placement from delivery and distinct site from delivery.

I am running 3 different SQL Select for this.

Is there a way we can find this from one single query as running multiple query slows it table has variety of data...

Currently i am using:-

```
SELECT 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT campaign SEPARATOR '^^') FROM delivery ) as campaign,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT placement SEPARATOR '^^') FROM delivery ) as placement,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT site SEPARATOR '^^' ) FROM delivery ) as site";
```

This has performance issues, do we have better solution than this.?

Comment: Might be better approach to redesign the table

Comment: hi @MichaelDibbets, this is not possible as this table is provided by my adserver....

Comment: In SQL `SELECT DISTINCT` is a "row operator", it performs over the whole row. So, if trying to describe requirements be very careful how you use the term "distinct" - because it implies "whole row". You are asking for a set of unique values of EACH field. (Not a distinct row comprising 3 columns.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GROUP BY clause with the three fields:

```
SELECT campaign, placement, site FROM table_foo GROUP BY campaign, placement, site
```

One significant issue with this, which will apply in this case as you say it is a "huge" table, is that this will use a temporary table and perform a file sort, and both of those can have performance issues.

Comment: This will not work as it will give me the set of distinct campaign, placement and site. like A, b,c;a,b1,c where a* is campaign and b* is placement and c* is site.

Comment: In that case, if there are 20 campaigns, 10 placements, and 3000 sites, it should be clear that a single query cannot produce a result that has both 20, and 10, and 3000 rows as the response.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one query, but it won't be any more efficient than running the 3 subqueries it needs separately.

```
select distinct 'campaign' as type, campaign as value 
union all
select distinct 'placement', placement
union all
select distinct 'site', site
```

This suggestion was prepared before the existing query was visible in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the server you are on, but if most recent data is not the highest priority, you could let a cron job run every 5 minutes with the data fields you want, and use a SELECT INTO to select it into a "compiled" database table from which you select your data.

Plain selecting data from a database table is much faster than the operations you are doing now, so there should be a significant speed increase. Only downside is your data will be behind every 5 minutes. But usually super accurate real time data is not really a requirement.

Other than this I don't see a real way to improve that, especially since you are using concat(string operations are tediously slow)

Comment: Hi, there are some cases when i have to fetch these columns values as per requirment as well, like if i want to fetch these records where impressions > 10000; and so on, then this approch will won't work..